# Chrome console has to click to see variable?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Chrome would usually display all my console.log fine no problem.

All of sudden anything in an object or array looks like this:

```
error:(...)
```

Then i have to click (...) to see the value.

Current setup:

Angular 4 via webclipse angular 4 ide (running in ide server)

What do i have to do to see the variable-data with clicking on it (how it used to be)

Comment: Is your console open when the message is logged?

Comment: yes, it's open on the side

Comment: Also for each variable it add a get and set function?